# How to get the TSP using DP algorithm can use 40 vertices?

Tags: dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman, search-problem

I`m currently doing my homework that solving TSP using DP algorithm or branch and bound algorithm or backtracking algorithm only to solve up to 40 vertices and I can solve up to 30 vertices when I try 35, it get bad_alloc at memory location 0x00000059F29EEB30. I try to figure out the algorithm but it doesn't get any better. Any solution to this ? Thanks so much.
Here is the code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

const int INF = numeric_limits<int>::max();

int tsp(int n, vector<vector<int>>& graph, vector<int>& dp, unsigned long long mask, int pos) {
    if (mask == (1ULL << n) - 1) {
        // All cities have been visited, return to the starting city
        return graph[pos][0];
    }

    if (dp[mask] != -1) {
        // The subproblem has already been solved
        return dp[mask];
    }

    int minCost = INF;

    // Try to visit every unvisited city
    for (int nextCity = 0; nextCity < n; ++nextCity) {
        if ((mask & (1ULL << nextCity)) == 0) {
            unsigned long long newMask = mask | (1ULL << nextCity);
            int cost = graph[pos][nextCity] + tsp(n, graph, dp, newMask, nextCity);
            minCost = min(minCost, cost);
        }
    }

    // Memoize the result
    dp[mask] = minCost;

    return minCost;
}

int main() {
    ifstream inputFile("input.txt");

    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening input file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int n;
    inputFile >> n;

    // Initialize the graph with distances between cities
    vector<vector<int>> graph(n, vector<int>(n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            inputFile >> graph[i][j];

    // Close the input file
    inputFile.close();

    // Initialize the memoization table using a column array
    vector<int> dp(1ULL << n, -1);

    // Start from city 0
    unsigned long long mask = 1ULL;
    int pos = 0;

    // Solve the TSP
    int minCost = tsp(n, graph, dp, mask, pos);


    // Write the result to the output file
    cout << "Minimum cost of the TSP: " << minCost << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and can use any type of code language like Java or Python or C++

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange! We discuss computer *science*, not programming which belongs to Stack Overflow. Please replace the code with concise pseudocode. This means, remove everything outside the TSP function, remove data types, remove braces, remove semicolons, remove comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided uses dynamic programming on travelling salesman problem, which has a time complexity of $O(2^n n^2)$, better than $O(n!)$ for brute force but very slow for $n = 40$. Worse is that it has a space complexity of $O(2^n n)$ for memoization, which would require RAM in the terabytes. It is not known whether there is a classical algorithm faster than $O(2^n)$, or a quantum algorithm faster than $O(\sqrt{3}^n)$.

However there are other approaches that are often faster in practice such as branch and bound which can handle $n$ in the thousands or incorporating plane-cutting into branch and cut which solved $n = 85900$ points in 2006. If the solution need not be exact, only $2-3\%$ from being optimal, then heuristics approaches such as Lin-Kernighan can handle $n$ in the millions. Read [travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computing_a_solution) wikipedia page.